# How to delete a specific row from a datatable based on a specific value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

```
private void DeleteMSISDN(string MSISDN)
    {
        DataTable dt = MSISDNTable();

        dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("MSISDN") == MSISDN).ToList().ForEach(row => row.Delete());

    }
```

When i do like this I am getting an Exception `System.Data.DeletedRowInaccessibleException`

Comment: List<DataRow> deleteRows = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("MSISDN") == MSISDN).ToList();  foreach (DataRow row in deleteRows) row.Delete();

Comment: @jdweng Any thoughts on why the OP code doesn't work? Assuming your code works, his version looks fine, too (though it's an oneliner). And you could post it as an answer.

Comment: @AdamJoan post a *reproducible* example. Does `MSISDNTable` return the *same* DataTable perhaps, resulting in an iteration over already deleted rows?

Comment: @AdamJoan also post the *full* exception including its call stack. Right now you/we don't know *where* the exception is trhown. It could be the call to `.Delete()`, it could be the call to `.Field`. You can get it with `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: The foreach has a MoveNext and when the last item is deleted you can't do the MoveNext.

Comment: @jdweng I'm looking at the [`List<T>` source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/90b323fe52bec428fe4bd5f007e9ead6b265d553/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) and `ForEach` uses a simple `for`. There is no `MoveNext()`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't have the rep to add this as a comment, but how is `MSISDNTable();` retrieving the table?

Could you have another process that is deleting rows before this function is executed? If `dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("MSISDN") == MSISDN)` errors when stripped of the ForEach delete then you will know something.